# Importing Netbeans project to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, swing, hibernate, netbeans, migration

I have created a GUI Applicaiton using Netbeans because of several obvious reasons like GUI Builders and all.

Now I want to implement Hibernate as ORM in this app in eclipse , because of the Hibernate plugin that makes it very simple and time saving .

How can i import that Netbeans project to my Eclipse IDE . I know there is no direct solution for this .

I have tried to find (.war) file under dist, but its not there even after clean and build in netbeans.  So please tell me a way to make it done .

Comment: You can create a new project from existing source in Eclipse. See [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736631/sharing-a-project-between-eclipse-and-netbeans)

Comment: -1 for what , atleast do mention the problem in question.

Comment: [Here's a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637735/what-is-src-directory-created-by-eclipse/2637787#2637787). Hope it helps!

Comment: *@Fares A* Actually, that's more or less what I linked to. The answer I linked to provides two links (`Netbeans <-> Eclipse`)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the similar problem. What I did was I copied .project and .classpath files (from my other eclipse project or you can create it, I was too lazy) into the netbeans project directory and then simply imported the project into eclipse. now I can make UI changes in netbeans and edit the other part in eclipse.

For the problem of AbsoluteLayout you need to make a classpath entry in ".classpath" file for AbsoluteLayout.jar

Hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem with my project the best way to solve this issue to do the configuration manually on eclipse. Its tiresome but there is no shorcut way to it..

1. Goto eclipse and create dynamic webproject
2. Create the simlar packages
3. Create same folder in the WEB-INF directory
4. Paste all the content(Source code, jsp file, js, css etc.)

Comment: dint work, my SWING project contains absolute layout , and thats what showing errors in Eclipse..